# Bot mention as a prefix in Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

My prefix only works if I do not add spaces to the entire command, example:

```
{
    "token": "",
    "prefix": "<@453463055741747200>"
}


const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    let something = args.join(" ");
    message.delete().catch();
    message.channel.send(something);
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "say"
}
```

Let's say my bot name is `MyBot`, the above code would only work with `@MyBot` say this, how can I make it work when the command is `@MyBot` say this?

Comment: What if you add a space to the prefix? So like this: `"prefix": "<@453463055741747200> "`

Comment: That does not work unfortunately

Comment: Can you please tell us how you're creating the arguments? Maybe edit the question and include another code section with the argument function

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this won't work, because I don't use a command handler so I have a different code style, but you can try what I use to allow my bot to be used with multiple global prefixes:

```
var prefixes = require('./prefixes.json')
//in your case can only be var prefixes = ["<@453463055741747200>", "<@!453463055741747200>"]

let prefix = false;
for (const thisPrefix of prefixes) {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(thisPrefix)) prefix = thisPrefix;
}
```

So the message just needs to start with the desired prefix. Also, I added two mention prefixes because discord is dumb and has two types of user mentions: nickname mentions and normal mentions. So in your code the bot will not work if it has a nick. That's why I added **<@!453463055741747200>** as well. Hope this helps you