# Discord.js v12 mention as bot prefix

Tags: javascript

how i can set mention as prefix for Discord.js bot in v12
I am using :

```
client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).split(" ");
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;
 if (message.channel.type === "dm") return

if (command === "test") {
message.reply("test")
}
})
```

I tryid to add <@${client.user.id}> to config.json as prefix and it didnt worked.
pls help

Answer (score 0):

If by setting a mention as a prefix you mean starting a command with a tagged user, I suggest you do it like this. Let's say that the command is **@user respond**

```
//this looks for a command with "respond" as a second word (argument) 
  if(args[1] === respond){
    // this defines the user you tagged as the first user tagged in the message
    taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
    //this sends a message with the tagged user
    message.channel.send('you tagged ' + taggedUser)
```

Edit: if you want the bot to respond to commands when it's tagged, then do something like:

```
const prefix = '<@bot-id>'
```

and put your bot id in there.

To help on how to find the bot prefix, look up discord developer mode.
To more help on this code, look at this question posted some time ago: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698019/bot-mention-as-a-prefix-in-discord-js)

Comment: I didnt meant this. I mean how to set bot mention as a prefix. For example: @(bot mention) test             bot should reply with test

Comment: @Anonymyous I edited the answer, hope it's the right one

Answer (score 0):

To set the prefix as mentioning the bot, all you need to do is obtain the client ID of the bot which can be done using [this guide](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-) made by Discord

Once you have the ID copied, go to your botconfig.json. Should look like this

```
{
  token: 'tokenhere',
  prefix: '<@!ClientID>'
}
```

Explanation: As a precaution against nickname changes of the bot, the '!' in the mention provides the bot with a way to detect it being pinged even if the nickname is changed